# How do I add database pooling - Spring3, Hibernate, MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Spring3, Hibernate, MySQL: I am working on my first project, can some one please show me how to change the following code to add database pooling? thanks

applicationContext-security-JDBC.xml

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
            <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
            <beans:property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
            <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        </beans:bean>
```

jdbc.properties

```
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db_mytest
database.user=root
database.password=
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

thanks.... again

Comment: what app server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [commons-dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). You have to download the jar and add it to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory (if not already included in your application server). This is your new applicationContext.xml with some default parameters that you should change as you wish:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="300000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="6" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="100" />
</bean>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: your configuration helped me with a "Too many connections" server error even though it had less active connections that what I had in my config, it might me the time between eviction, or pool prepared statement.. im going to comment some of them out, now, and see which one was the config I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you are running your application on. Many application servers have their own connection pooling implementation that you can tap into. I've used Tomcat's DBCP in the past - was quite easy to set up.